# Many to Many Relationship in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am currently trying to design my django models for the following situations: I have a class that is called User and every user has a unique userid. Now I want to do a ranking, based on the coins a user has. However, I want to make only users that are friends visible to the user when the user views the ranking.

Therefore I am defining a class Friends that has a ManytoMany field “isfriend” that contains all the userids that the User is friends with. However, I feel that the way I am trying to do this is not the best way to go. Any suggestions how I should implement this?

```
class User(models.Model):
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=26,unique=True)
    coins = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.userid

class Friends(models.Model):
    isfriend = models.ManytoManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.isfriend
```

Comment: Why you don't simply add a `friends` field to your User, and it has ManytoMany relation ?

Comment: the reason was because I wasnt sure that it would work in the same table. So according to you I could just add friends = models.ManytoManyField(User) to the user table and it would be all good?

Comment: Just replace `(User)` by `'self'`, I mean `friends = models.ManyToManyField('self')`

Comment: ok, thanks! I'll try it this way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User has Many User (friends), it gives a solution like:

```
class User(models.Model):
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=26,unique=True)
    coins = models.IntegerField()
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.userid
```

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: one more question. how would I populate this many-to-many field in this case?

user = User.objects.get(userid=id)

friendsid = "101"

user.friends.add(friendsid)

seems not work. It returns me django.db.utils.DataError: integer out of range